# Run methods as service c#?

Tags: c#, service

I have a couple of methods that do processing after fetching data.I need call these five services in order 1-5,well I would like to make it a exe that can run from the windows scheduler (so that I don't have to write my own scheduling code).The main reason for this exe is so that it can be run on a server rather than on a desktop and do the processing faster.So I was thinking

Make an exe In the exe call the services in the order 1-5 (use  threading?)

Log events to event log     for exception

Schedule the exe to    run from (which account)

Profit    ????

Comment: Why do you need threads if they run one after the other?

Comment: Instead of an exe that calls all five programs, why not use a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions that should do the trick:

### Easy/Fast/Less Capable

- Follow Treb's suggestion of using a batch file to call each child executable.
- In the batch file, redirect the output of each child process to a text file (instead of logging to the Event Log).
- Use the Windows Scheduler to launch the batch file.
- Ideally, you'd run the batch file with the **LocalService** account.

### A Bit More Work/Slightly More Capable

- Create a new executable that will launch the five others.
- This new parent process will capture the output of its child processes ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net)), writing it to the Event Log.
- Run the parent with the Windows Scheduler; again, using the **LocalService** account.