# Using a command line program from within a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface

I have written a C++ program (which executes from the command line), that works fine. Now I need to use it for my C# application. That is to say, I would like the output from my C++ program to be used in my C# application whenever it is called.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Any links or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to fire up your C++ program and redirect its output to a stream for use in your C# application. The information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net) details the specifics:

```
string command = "arg1 arg2 arg3"; // command line args
string exec = "filename.exe";      // executable name
string retMessage = String.Empty;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process p = new Process();

startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.Arguments = command;
startInfo.FileName = exec;

p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();

using (StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput)
{
    retMessage = output.ReadToEnd();
}

p.WaitForExit();

return retMessage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your C++ code DLL, and use pinvoke to call the C++ functions from C# code.

Read this article: [Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

Another way to do this is to use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class from .Net. Using Process, you don't need to make your C++ code DLL; you can start your C++ EXE as a process from C# code.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your C++ program write it's output to a file, and have your C# program read from the file.

If your application is very performance sensitive, then this is not the best way.

Here is the C# code to run the C++ program:

```
        try
        {
            Process p = StartProcess(ExecutableFileName);
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch
        {
            Log("The program failed to execute.");
        }
```

Now you are left to write to the file from your C++ program, and read from it in your C# program.

This will show you how to write to a file from your C++ program:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

This will show you how to read from a file in your C# program:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems the OP didn't leave any further comments, I am left wondering, would | not have sufficed?  I guess it comes down to the object that is the "it" in "**whenever it is called**".  If "it" refers to the C++ program, then Andy Mikula's answer is best.  If "it" refers to the C# program, then I would suggest:

```
C:\>myCpluplus.exe | myCsharp.exe
```

and simply read from Console.In within myCsharp.exe.