# Get the output of a console program in my WinForms application (Specifically the output of C# compiler - CSC.EXE)

Tags: c#

I decided to do something really simple -

A WinForms application with a text box for C# code and a button. When the button is clicked, I save the content of the text box to a temp .cs file, invoke the csc.exe (Process.Start()) with the file name as parameter so that it is compiled. This is assuming I set the PATH variables and everything.

When the csc.exe outputs syntax errors and stuff, how can I get it back and show it in another text box in my app?

**NOTE** My aim is not to just "complie C# code from within my app (in whichever way possible)".. it is to get the output of csc.exe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments)

Comment: Well.. the other answer uses something called CodeDom. My question is not about "A way to compile C#". My question is about specifically using the csc.exe and get the output somehow. If I had asked "how can I compile C# from my program", it would be duplicate.

Comment: Edited question to make it clear: I need output of csc.exe Not just any way to compile C# code

Comment: Actually this is a duplicate of **[How to spawn a process and capture its STDOUT in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net)**

Comment: Hmmm.. Yep. Please close it! I was obsessed with CSC.exe I failed to think about it in a generic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to redirect stdout and stderr.

It goes along the lines of:

```
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
```

Then reading from `process.StandardInput`. I can't really remember if this is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use csc.exe [parameters] >output.file to stream the console output of csc.exe to a text file, and then read the text file into your text box.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ProcessStartInfo class to redirect the console output to a stream of yours, then display the stream content in your windows control.

You can also take a look a the CodeDom namespace to produce on the fly assemblies, but it depends on your goal and requirement.