# Execute an exe in remote pc - C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, remote-access

I am looking for a way to execute my exe in a remote pc (Win2003) from another Admin Server (Win2003) and collect the output generated by that exe.

My app.exe (for eg) will execute and write information to a text file. I also want to read this text file (this is in remote server) from a Admin Server.

I know the path of the exe in the remote system and also know the text file path which will be generated. But i dont know how to execute the app.exe from a remote server using VC++/C++.

Looking for help.

Thanks 
Raghu

Comment: if it were easy it would be a problem

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Answer (score 0):

You should create some service on the target machine ( a WCF service for example ) hosted on IIS or preferable in a window service, ensure that service have all the permission needed to run the executable, then shell it and [collect the standard output as shown for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net). from the remote machine then you can call the service and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe [**WinRM**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (*Windows Remote Management*) will be useful for your purpose. You can read an introduction [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/09/24/an-introduction-to-winrm-basics.aspx).

["Windows Remote Management"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on msdn.microsoft.com.

As to me, I was working with this technology a few years ago. But I was using C# instead of C++ (don't worry, link I provided is about C++ API). Thereat I implemented a remote RS232 (comport) handling. WinRM allows you to do many cool things (for another example, you can control a process on a remote computer).

Answer (score 0):

If the application (executable) is already installed on the remote machine(s), you can use WMI to spawn process on the remote machine.

Use Win32_Process and execute Create method.