# How do I read from a process output

Tags: c#, wrapper, minecraft

Im trying to create a minecraft server wrapper but im having trouble reading the output of the process. I want to read the output in the serverProcess_ErrorDataRecevied event and I know that what there is now doesn't work. But what could I put there instead to read it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace MC_Server_UI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe", "Xmx1024M - jar " + "craftbukkit.jar" + " nogui");
        Process serverProcess;

        OpenFileDialog ofd;
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            fbd.ShowDialog();

            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = fbd.SelectedPath;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            serverProcess = new Process();
            serverProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            serverProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            serverProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(serverProcess_ErrorDataReceived);
            serverProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(serverProcess_Exited);
            serverProcess.Start();
        }

        private void serverProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(serverProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
        }

        private void serverProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See:

- [How to spawn a process and capture its STDOUT in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net)
- [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Code:

```
serverProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
serverProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", args.Data);
serverProcess.Start();
serverProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Or:

```
serverProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
var output = serverProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

See also: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx)

```
serverProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
var error = serverProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question. I have redirected the streams and using .ReadToEnd doesn't work.

Comment: The `StandardError` and `StandardOutput` is a `StreamReader`. You can use that to pull output from the process. The `OutputDataReceived` is an event that will also work.

Comment: After some testing I notice that the event will only trigger if I have done .BeginErrorReadLine but using .ReadToEnd will then throw an exception.