# StandardOutput Process

Tags: c#, .net, process, redirectstandardoutput

For my programe i need decompile a swf ... I use flasm for this !

for my first try i export result in txt file and read this txt

```
string newPath = Path.GetTempPath() + @"DasLol.txt";

        if(File.Exists(newPath))
        {
            File.Delete(newPath);
        }

        string dasCmd = "/c flasm.exe -d \"" + path + "\" > " + newPath;

        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", dasCmd);

        Process flasm = new Process {StartInfo = procStartInfo};

        flasm.Start();
        flasm.WaitForExit();
string dasString = File.ReadAllText(newPath);
```

but how to redirect de StandardOutput for read directly my "dasString" in console ?
( and don't use a temporary txt )

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Allow the standard output to be redirected, wait for the process to exit, read it.

```
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandartOutput = true;
...
flasm.WaitForExit();
string output = flasm.StandartOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: didn't work !!

if procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
console appears, but the command ("dasCmd") is not executed.

( PS new dasCmd ; string dasCmd = "/c flasm.exe -d \"" + path + "\" "; )

Comment: What do you mean it's not executed?