# Retrieving python output as c# input

Tags: c#, python

We know that we can run python functions in c# and invoking the console and we can get python output in c# in the python console but whats the use of that if we cannot the python output as the c# input ? it would be useless integration so my question is :
how do you retrieve python output as c# input ?
can you import variables from python to c#?
how do you that ?

I'm calling python function in c# and the out put is still in python console but can it be used in c# for example if I return python function in c# can i declare it as variable to use it in my c# program ?

that's all thank you  help me :)

Comment: Could you explain a bit better what you are trying to do? It seems you might be running python in a separate shell. You could look into the `Process` class that lets you redirect `STDOUT`. Or, you could look into IronPython for a .NET version of Python.

Comment: im trying to get the python output and use it in c# as input

Comment: well... how are you producing the output? show me some code please.

Comment: right now i just can call python function through c# and the output will be produced into the popped up python console that means by calling the function the c# calls the console as well through the engine function that is available

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It takes a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) argument that lets you redirect standard output - this is what gets printed to the console when you `print "hello, world!"` in python.

Check this question here for more information on how to do it: [How to spawn a process and capture its STDOUT in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net)