# CMD closes after a second

Tags: c#, cmd

So after pressing the "Launch" button, CMD opens up and closes right after a second or so. As you can see, I'm trying to open an .exe file through CMD with a parameter line. It works when I do it manually, but when I put into C#...

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

String host = textBox1.Text;

String fp = textBox2.Text;

String port = textBox4.Text;

String time = textBox5.Text;

String threads = textBox3.Text;

String type = "GET";

string param = string.Format( " /C {0} start C:/Dos.exe " + host + port + fp + time + threads + type, Environment.NewLine);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", param).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: First thing I'd recommend to do is to [capture the process' output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net) and then post it here. That will make troubleshooting much easier, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use Console.Read() at the end so that the cmd waits for a key to be pressed before it closes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use command parameter K instead of C I mean

```
string param = string.Format( " /K {0} start C:/Dos.exe " + host + port + fp + time + threads + type, Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `/C` flag on the command line for the CMD.EXE followed by the `start` option, this means that your console launches the DOS.EXE program as a `separate process` and then exits.

In this way the process of CMD.EXE is already terminated when you call WaitForExit

If you want to wait on the CMD.EXE process then don't use the `start` option

```
string param = string.Format(" /C {0} C:/Dos.exe " + ....., Environment.NewLine);
```

It is not clear what is the reason to add a newline after the /C flag

Comment: That sounds like a solution. What should I use instead of **start**?

Comment: Have you tryed to remove the start keyword?. On my side it opens the console window and waits. Of course the console window is not usable because it is waiting the DOS.EXE process to terminate. But I am wondering why you don't try to start directly the DOS.EXE program instead of CMD.EXE and then DOS.EXE

Comment: I tried to launch Dos.exe directly, but the same thing happens. Also, I get an error when I remove the **start**. What's wrong??

Comment: I don't know this DOS.EXE program. It is possible that something is not correct in the parameter list. You could try to change the /C in /K to capture the output of DOS.EXE in the console window and look if there is some error message