# Asp.net C#, getting Microsoft RDS user session

Tags: asp.net, remote-desktop

Is it possible to retrieve from a RDS server de user session list and show it on a asp.net webpage.

My main goal is to give a page where the users can logout their sessions when the sessions are "stucked".

Answer (score 0):

You can get the session list and logout users [from the command line](http://anandthearchitect.com/2008/08/01/how-to-logoff-remote-desktop-sessions-via-command-line-tools/):

```
qwinsta /server:yourserver

logoff /server:yourserver 1 /v
```

So, you could use [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) to run these commands from your web application.

Comment: Humm, and how can i manipulate the data from received from those commands?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net