# Passing a value as an argument in C# to python and receiving the processed value from Python and display on C# forms

Tags: c#, python

I am making an application with visual c# in the front end and Python executing the scripts in the back end. I wanted to pass one value from Visual c# form as an argument to a Python script. The Python script should process the value and should return the processed value to Visual c#. The value should be displayed in the visual c# form.

For the first thing, I wrote a dirty code where python script is executed when the form is loaded and store the value in a text file. Python script will use the value to calculate. But I am not able to return the value to c#.

The code which I wrote for the first logic is:

```
Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\c#\Work\RulesValidator\RulesValidator\Asset_Id.py";
        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        asset_id.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\c#\Work\RulesValidator\RulesValidator\Asset_Id.txt");
```

Comment: Have you looked into IronPython which is custom built for this type of thing? http://ironpython.net/

Comment: @Daniel.. I went through the iron python notes but didnt get much. I will check that option now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you start the child Python script and immediately try to read the sequential file **without waiting for the end of the child**.

You should try :

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\c#\Work\RulesValidator\RulesValidator\Asset_Id.py";
try
{
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit(); // Now child should have done its job and closed file
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
asset_id.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\c#\Work\RulesValidator\RulesValidator\Asset_Id.txt");
```

But you should investigate the way proposed by e-nouri. The only attention point is : *To use StandardOutput, you must set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to false*. On the Python part, you would only write the *result* to stdout, every other output going to stderr.

It could be (adapted from [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN) :

```
 // Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\c#\Path\To\python.exe";
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\c#\Work\RulesValidator\RulesValidator\Asset_Id.py";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

BEWARE : I've no C# developpement environment and above is untested even if I honestly think it should not be far from what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can spawn a process and capture its stdout, here is an SO question for this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net).
In your python program/script you can just use prints that will print to the stdout, then capture it from your C# code. Depends the complexity of that data you want to exchange, you can use plain text, json, etc.

Cheers,