# Mysqldump Not Working Inside the query

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm creating a back up Window Forms C# application but my code doesn't work. :(

Here's my code:

```
Data dt = new Data();
dt.Connection();
try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("mysqldump -u root -p mypass mydb > backup.sql", dt.connect);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch{
}
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation carefully and then probably you can download the source files from the Link I have given you on the last question. To see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

MySQLDump is not a SQL command, it is a command-line utility.

You can [use Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net) to run it and capture the output.

Note that mysqldump.exe needs to be in your PATH environment variable, or you need to specify a complete path to it.