# How to make function for dll (c++) from main function to use in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

I need to use my c++ code in c# application. I thought about pinvoke, but I'm confused with the approach I should take for creating dll from my c++ app.
Basically, my c++ app is a `main` function, which runs an endless loop of data processing and I dont know how I can export such thing to dll and call it from c#.

I tried to rewrite my `main` function in standalone `init` function for dll and call it from c#, but because its a endless loop it never came to the point with `return` from function. And I dont know how to get my data buffer from endless loop at some point to my c# app.

What I've done currently:

```
// myDLL.cpp
int __stdcall OpenRTSP(char url, char progname)
{
    TaskScheduler* scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
    UsageEnvironment* env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

    if (openURL(*env, &progname, &url) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // All subsequent activity takes place within the event loop:
    // This function call does not return, unless programm closes.
    env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop(&eventLoopWatchVariable);

   return 0;
}

// myDLL.h
__declspec(dllexport)  int __stdcall OpenRTSP(char url, char progname);
```

I dont know how to call OpenRTSP from c#, because it will never return from this func and how to write a function, which will return me a data buffer from endless loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your C++ program runs a continuous process, you'd probably better leave it a standalone process and run it from your C# code using [`Process` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx). The data from you C++ process can be passed by virtue of some IPC methods. The simple STDOUT seems to fit your task quite well. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net) describes how it can be achieved.

Here's a brief code sample:

```
var cppProcess = new Process();
cppProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "YourCppApp.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
};
cppProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, arg) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", arg.Data);
};
cppProcess.Start();
cppProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

If the buffer you send back from the C++ app should rather be binary, use `BinaryReader` to read from the C++ app's STDOUT:

```
var cppProcess = new Process();
cppProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "YourCppApp.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
};
cppProcess.Start();
using (var cppOutput = new BinaryReader(cppProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream))
    while (!cppProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead= cppOutput.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // Process the buffer...
    }
```

---

Alternatively, you may change your `main` function to a library function as you have already tried to do and pass it a callback function from C# as a parameters. But this would be more tedious and I personally would not go for this in your particular case.

Comment: After some working I've found that standalone process is much faster than  `dllimport` way. Thanks for help. Also, to clarify things for other people - I've tested it with pipe data transfer between c++ and c#.

Answer (score 0):

If the function you need is indeed `main()` and you don't need to interact with your C# application you can run your executable as an external process. Look at the documentation of `System.Diagnostics.Process` how to do that.

If this is not the right option for you then try to call your blocking function via P/Invoke from a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CLR project and import it to c#, if you have the full c++ code it won't be a problem.

To do it just: New Project->C++->CLR->Class library.
Then on the header you write something like this:

```
// filename.h
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace YourNampespace
{
  public ref class YourClass abstract sealed
  {
    //int __stdcall OpenRTSP(char url, char progname);
    //You want to convert this to managed, buf if you return "int", with "char" params,
    // it won't be a problem
  }
}
```

Then on the source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "filename.h"
int YourNampespace::YourClass::__stdcall OpenRTSP(char url, char progname)
{
 //Code here
}
```

I almost don't know any c++ and I'm not sure what do you mean by "endless loop of data processing"¨, but you could write the which data is "sent" to a stream, return it to the c# app and read it from there. No interprocess things (I think that would bring more problems)