# Run command line command passing STDIN

Tags: c#, terminal, console, stdout, stdin

## This is not a duplicate, see bolded parts; please vote to re-open

I am attempting to execute an external application via C#.

I wish to **pass `stdin`** into the started application, and capture the result.

The equivalent bash command would be:

```sh
echo Typist 1 . 0 | figlet-2.2.5/figlet -f Slant
```

In C#, how can I run the above command and store its `stdout` into a variable?

---

I have tried using `Process.Start("figlet-2.2.5/figlet", "-f Slant")`, but this doesn't work because the application:

1. **needs data via `stdin`**
2. **requires parameters to be supplied**
3. and provides output via `stdout`

Comment: Why not use Process.Start to execute a batch script or PowerShell script? How do you plan to store the stdout?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I don't know how to store the stdout. That is why I am asking this question. "store the STDOUT output of the above command into _**some variable.**_"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net

Comment: @EJoshuaS I don't understand the top answer on that question. I am very new to C#.

Comment: @EJoshuaS `OutputDataReceived` is some kind of event listener?

Comment: To clarify my above question, what you mean by "store?" What do you intend to do with the stdout information once you have it (write to file, store to database, etc.)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS once I have it, I'd eventually like to write it to stdout itself

Comment: I'm confused - if it was already written to stdout why would you write it there again?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I want to take `echo Typist 1 . 0 | figlet-2.2.5/figlet -f Slant`'s stdout and store it in a string variable.

Comment: The code in the linked article should work for that purpose.

Comment: @EJoshuaS but I am needing to pass some info on stdin as well as command-line flags.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Part of it (i.e. a part that by itself _might_ arguably not be too broad) is answered by the marked duplicate. Really though your first step is to read the documentation for the `Process` class. It discusses in detail how redirection of the standard I/O streams work. Note that you don't necessarily have to use the `...DataReceived` events; the `Out` and `Error` properties return `TextReader` objects which you can read asynchronously (e.g. `ReadLineAsync()`).

Comment: Microsoft provides a code sample for writing to stdin here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx