# Capture WinForms console messages (debug) from another program?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have created two DotNet programs.

Application A (main app) writes debug info to the console (console.writeline).

Is it possible for my Application B (debugger app) to catch these console messages from Application A?

Both Windows Forms applications are located on the same Pc.

Thanks.

Comment: I think [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net) has the right answer

Comment: @MooNDeaR sry for not being clear (I updated my question) ... it's two WinForms applications - not console applications.